# What's the difference between Textures and VertexTextures in XNA?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, textures, performance, hlsl

The `GraphicsDevice` class of XNA has the properties `Textures` and `VertexTextures`.

What is the exact difference? I don't really understand what MSDN tells me about this.

I usually use `Effect` parameters to pass textures to my HLSL shaders. What are the differences between these methods, which is faster?

Comment: No one should be faster. In DX there is bindtoVertex and bindToPixel. They just bind a resource for a certain stage in the shader.

Comment: Ok this means I could use a Texture in the Vertex Shader? For what is this useful? Getting VertexColor from a Texture to have some kind of very low res texture?

Comment: And what is the difference between passing a user texture as effect parameter and using the Textures collection?

Answer (score 2):

`GraphicsDevice.Textures` are your "traditional" textures; the one's you sample from during the fragment shader.

`GraphicsDevice.VertexTextures` are textures that you want to sample from in the *vertex* shader, which required specialized HLSL instructions (`texldl`, as noted in the documentation) on the D3D9-class hardware that XNA is based on. Vertex textures were a half-measure towards the more unified shader resource input pipe that is available on modern cards, but not via XNA. You probably do not need to concern yourself with the `VertexTextures` property for the time being.

Using the `Effect` API to send textures to the shader will, under the hood, do exactly the same set of steps that you would need to do if you manually assigned textures to specific samplers. I would recommend you continue to just use the `Effect` methods as they are likely going to be easier for you, since you already understand them.